# How to split content for different target audience?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, multi-sites

We're having a bit of a difficulty finding the best way to solve the current issue: it's a multi-site and multi-lingual set-up for a customer that is active in different countries. For each country a separate database is uses (multi-site) and each country has an English + local language variation (multi-lingual).

The customer also has a split audience (private vs. business) and all pages have a one-to-one match, meaning if you are on a `/en/private/foo` page, you could go to `/en/business/foo` just by switching the target audience (same way the language switcher works).

The problem is you'll have two switcher blocks on the page that have to be in sync:

- language (english/local language)
- audience (private/business)

How would you split the content and keep the relation between the different nodes for different audience groups? This also has impact on other Drupal components, the menu for example.

We've been looking at two different approaches:

- separation on content level (taxonomy or field to select the audience
  group)
- grouping the content (e.g. [`og`](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module, or the new kid on the block [`group`](https://www.drupal.org/project/group))

Any people out there that had the same issue and how did you solve it?

Comment: You can just add Context plugin + some switch.

Comment: Great question I'm interested in doing the same with countries on D8 (have 1 site, but be able to switch country as well as language for content sorting and have it in url like language.) So please do post your solution once you have it :)

Comment: @IvanJaros What exactly do you mean with _just add `Context`_. Could you expand on your answer, how could `Context` solve this issue?

Comment: If you edit a block you can see display rules like content type, page, user role...all of those are context plugins in block group. So you can create new context plugin, put it into "site" group or whatever and then use context plugin manager in your logic.

Comment: @Max : what do you have in place (or how do you enforce) that "**all pages have a one-to-one match**"? E.g. the moment you create a new (say) business-page, you can impossibly (at the very same moment) also have a (say) private-page equivalent? Or is it OK to assume that for any (say) business-page there "might be" some private-page equivalent with a path in which "business" is changed to "private"?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens there's indeed business/private included in the URL. But that's not something we want to rely on. We've looked at the [`relation`](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) module which is what we need, but it's not yet ready for D8. So right now, we're just using an entity reference field, on both private and business bundles. And to avoid having to manually link on both ends, inside a `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave` we update the counterpart. And then we just have a custom block, that pulls the current node from the menu router and then we get the counterpart node.

Answer (score 2):

@max I am assuming that since there is a 1-1 relation between 'private' and 'business' content, you are probably just hiding (restricting) content in on of the two.  So if for example, your 'private' content is only available to authenticated users, or user who paid for the content, then essentially the other (business) content is a reduced version (teaser)?

If that is the case, then maybe you can consider using different display modes for the same node - in other words, you only have one node for both business and private, but with different view modes.  The one with restricted access (lets assume that is business) will show nodes using the 'teaser' view, while the other will render the node using the 'full' display mode.

It should be easy enough to change the display mode dynamically on load / render based on the user's status (logged in, paid for content, etc).

The other option, and you could even combine this, is to use content access modules, specifically [field level access](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions), to automatically control which fields will be rendered or not.  So in this configuration, you could always render the node using the same (possibly different) display modes, but based on the authentication level of the user, simply do not show the field: I can confirm that I have personally used this and it does work (http://www.startnetwork.org).

All things being equal, I would personally only have one node (as opposed to 2 implicitly related nodes) and then simply control what information (or how much) is shown.

If you have any questions - please let me know: happy to help.

Comment: it's actually not restricted based on the user roles. That would have made it a lot easier. By private, I meant private individuals. Sorry for the confusion. I do like your idea for combining the private/business in a single node and then restricting depending on the context. Will look into it.

Comment: Ah yes - OK I understand.  Still believe the two possibilities listed above will work.  Please let me know if you have any questions: happy to help.

Comment: One last thing JP, you're idea is looking promising but it has one small shortcoming. By having a single node, there's a single path alias and we need 2 different aliases for each target audience group. Something like `/private/foo` and `business/foo`.

Comment: Hi @max - this may solve that problem: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/pathauto.  Basically we define an alias.  So the 'default' path could be /private/???? and then using PathAuto we always define an alias using a pattern /business/????

Comment: Yes, `pathauto` is being used, but it doesn't allow multiple URL aliases for the same node. I just tried it and in D8 and you can specify multiple patterns for the same entity type and bundle, but it will only generate a single alias. And I don't see a _default_ pattern option.

Comment: I quickly tested, and it looks like the path module (part of Drupal core: `admin/config/search/path`) allows you to have multiple aliases for the same node.  See here for more information : https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/path

Comment: I know, but you cannot have multiple patterns for the same entity bundle type and language code combination. So for the english version of node `foo` you cannot have two aliases like `/business/foo` and `private/foo`. You can have create multiple patterns but in the end Drupal will only generate a single alias.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module to create a group for each country, and combine that with [using the subgroup sub-module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2710757) to implement 4 subgroups for each country:

- Business - English language.
- Private - English language.
- Business - Local language.
- Private - Local language.

That will give you already a solution that works for D8, with all the flexibility you need to organise (split) your content based on your target audience.

Since the Group module is fully entity based, you can take advantage of any type of typical functionality offered by modules such as the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

And for anything that requires custom code, you have various hooks available (refer to the [Development Guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2687559) for some more details on that).

Comment: Thanks @pierre-vriens, I had a look at this module and it's a nice solution for grouping the content. But that's half the battle, it doesn't solve the relationship between the different group types.